# Android doesn't execute create statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a new database in my Activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "create DatabaseOpenHelper");
    DatabaseOpenHandler helper = new DatabaseOpenHandler(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "get readable database access");
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Log.d(TAG, "create Cursor for database access");
    Cursor data = database.query(DatabaseConstants.TABLE_NOTES, fields,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    Log.d(TAG, "create SimpleCursorAdapter for ListView");
    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.conference_note_item, data, fields,
            new int[] { R.id.note_text });

    Log.d(TAG, "set ListAdapter");
    setListAdapter(dataSource);
}
```

but my DatabaseOpenHandler doesn't call the onCreate method.

```
public DatabaseOpenHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
            DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
    db.execSQL(DatabaseConstants.CREATE_TABLE_NOTES);
}
```

My SQL query:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NOTES + " (" + NOTE_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOTE_CONFERENCE
        + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_DATE + " INTEGER, " + NOTE_TEXT
        + " INTEGER);";
```

Comment: try    database = helper.getWriteableDatabase();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` lifecycle method is *only* called when the database *doesn't* already exist. It gets executed the first time when there is no database present. Assuming there are no errors in your code, change the name of the database in your dbadapter and it would get executed.

Comment: but when I'm reinstalling my app on the vd, it should be called. Shouldn't it?

Comment: If on uninstall of app the database isn't getting removed, it won't be called on app re-install as db already exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Oncreate** is only called **if the database does'nt exist**... and new database should be created.. and if already the database is created oncreate is not called..

Answer (score 0):

If you update the `DATABASE_VERSION`, then the `onUpgrade(...)` method of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation will get called, you can then use this to drop existing tables and recreate them (possibly by calling `onCreate(...)` explicitly).

This is what I do whenever I make changes to my database during development.

**Note:** when your app has been deployed you will probably want to do some nice migration logic, so as not to lose all your users data.

Some example code:

```
private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private String CLASS_NAME;

    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        CLASS_NAME = getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Logger.log(Level.VERBOSE, CLASS_NAME + " - onCreate",
                "Creating tables");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MY_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Logger.log(Level.VERBOSE, CLASS_NAME + " - onUpgrade",
                "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MY_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```